# Enable knockout.js-specific code highlighting in phpstorm/webstorm

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to enable knockout.js-specific code highlighting in phpstorm using language injections.
So far I was able to do so in `data-bind` XML attributes, which was pretty straightforward:

[image: Language Injection Settings window]

But I can't figure out how to create an injection for knockout-style comments `<!-- ko: --> <!-- /ko -->`

There is a generic xml injection in php storm, but I don't know what to put in the 'Places patterns' section:

[image: Places patterns settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible without a WebStorm/PHPStorm plugin.

```
<!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
    <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is one style of comment, you would need to set up language injection for the DSL (Domain Specific Language) of the knockout templating style, as well as getting it to handle the javascript inside the comment.

Since the 'if:' DSL inside the comment, doesn't register as a HTML attribute (It's wholly ignored as a comment), Doesn't match the attribute format, and that the feature doesn't have support for having comments have meaningful semantics, we are screwed.

Comment: thanks for the answer)
although I already moved to react and have no such problem now)